# Cannot stop Terminal script

Tags: linux, virtualenvwrapper

I have an issue where everytime I open Terminal, I see the following lines repeating over and over again:

"-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory

-bash: ^D: command not found"

I tried stopping this with Ctrl + C and Ctrl + Z, but this is only temporary. Same thing with shutting down my computer.

I also tried installing virtualenvwrapper.sh directly to the local bin, but this does not stop the issues. Any advice would be helpful because I have no way to stop this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like virtualenvwrapper installation failed at some point. Try to install again. If you just want to get rid of the messages look into **~/.profile** or **~/.bashrc** files. There should be line towards the ending that should look like :

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh